# jquery how to make sure that the user has selected a value for all select menus on a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form with multiple select menus i want to make sure on submit that a user selected a value for each select menu how can i do that with jquery ? i tried something like

```
var form = $('myform');
if($(form ).find('select').length != $(form).find('select:option[selected="selected"]').length ) { 
    alert('wrong please make sure to select all select menu');
}
```

but no luck

please help

Thank you

Comment: Please define "not selected". Usually, assuming a select with a size of 1 and without multiple-attribute the 1st option is always selected(if no selected-attribute is set somewhere else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form object has already been created.I removed the `$()` function from the form variables in the `if` statement. You should also be using an identifier for `myform`.

```
var form = $('form#myform');
if(form.find('select').length != form.find('select:option[selected="selected"]').length ) { 
    alert('wrong please make sure to select all select menu');
}
```

I recommend you prefix your `form` var with a `$` to note that you are already using a jquery object.

Example:

```
var $form = $('form#myform');
if($form.find('select').length != $form.find('select:option[selected="selected"]').length ) { 
    alert('wrong please make sure to select all select menu');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default select element's first option is selected if none of the options have `selected` attribute, so your selector will not work which is looking for `selected` attribute in the option element. Also if the `id` of the form is `myform` then you should use `#myform` to find it. Try this.

```
var $form = $('#myform');
if($form.find('select').length != $form.find('select:option:selected').length ) { 
    alert('wrong please make sure to select all select menu');
}
```